# Binding a Node.js Application on a Port with Nginx

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm trying to set a *Node.js Application for Production on a Port with SSL on Nginx Ubuntu 17.04*. So far I have `SSL Nginx` server up and running.

This is how my Nginx Configuration file looks like:

```
server {
listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server;
listen 443 ssl;

root /var/www/html;
index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

server_name example.com www.example.com;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
}

location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
}
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot

if ($scheme != "https") {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
} 

    ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;

}
```

This is how my Node.js Application looks lik:

```
#content of index.js    
'use strict';

const http = require('http');
http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8',
  });
  res.write('<h1>I’m a Node app!</h1>');
  res.end(3000, 'localhost')
}).listen();
console.log('http://example.com:3000/');
```

I would want to know how can I bind this Node.js Application on a Port with SSL with the existing Nginx configurations.

Comment: You have to bind the NodeJS application to a different port and then have Nginx proxy the request to it.

PS: Search for `nginx reverse proxy nodejs` and you will find plenty examples on how to set it up.

Comment: @razvanz thanks! that's my question actually :) okay! will do.

Comment: @razvanz eventually it is listening to `location /app2 {}` but it's show error **502 Bad Gateway**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my answer to question.
There were two mistakes:

1) Edit and addition to `server` closure file:

```
location ~ ^/(nodeApp|socket\.io) {
   proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
}
```

SocketIO uses /socket.io path by default, so one need to configure Nginx so that it will proxy not only /nodeApp request, but /socket.io too

2) One more edit in Node.js server file. Replace:

```
http.createServer((req, res) => {` to `app.get('/node', function(req, res) {
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use nginx as a reverse proxy to your nodejs application.

For example, make node run on port 3000, and do something like this in your nginx conf.

If the node app is the only thing in the server,

```
server {
   listen 443;
   <-- snip -->

   location / {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
   }

   <-- snip -->
}
```

If you have something else like a php application running on the server, create another server block and give a separate `server_name` for your app.

```
server {
   listen 443;
   server_name nodeapp.mysite.com;
   <-- snip -->

   location / {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
   }

   <-- snip -->
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) I needed both reverse proxy with web server. I've posted my answer.